# Face will not fill as expected

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

New to blender.
Trying to fill between four vertices but fill is creating a face between non-selected vertices next to those I have selected. [image]

[image]

How do I fill between the vertices i want and avoid filling non-chosen vertices ?

thankyou

also, could not see just a simple blender tag.

Comment: Just worked out that the different components need to be joined before the fill can happen, thankyou :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just worked out that the different components need to be joined before the fill can take place.
thanks